# Conduit and Attoparsec: unexpected termination on parse error

Tags: haskell, conduit, attoparsec

I'm trying to convert a log file parser that I wrote a while back over to conduit, and I'm running into an issue. I'll simplify the details of the parser itself since that's not relevant to the question. I have a log file that looks like this:

```
200 GET
404 POST
500 GET
FOO
301 PUT
302 GET
201 POST
```

So the parsing code is pretty straightforward:

```
data SimpleLogEntry = SimpleLogEntry {
      status :: Int
    , method :: String
} deriving (Show, Eq)


parseHTTPStatus :: Parser Int
parseHTTPStatus = validate <$> decimal
    where validate d = if (d >= 200 && d < 999) then d else 100


parseHTTPMethod :: Parser String
parseHTTPMethod =
        (stringCI "GET" *> return "Get")
    <|> (stringCI "POST" *> return "Post")
    <|> (stringCI "PUT" *> return "Put")
    <|> return "Unknown"


parseLogLine :: Parser SimpleLogEntry
parseLogLine = fmap SimpleLogEntry
        parseHTTPStatus
    <*> (space *> parseHTTPMethod)
```

So far so good. Here's how I implemented this in conduit:

```
import Prelude hiding (lines)

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT, ResourceT)
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.Attoparsec as CA
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL


logLines:: Source (ResourceT IO) B.ByteString
logLines = CB.sourceFile "~/test.log" $= CB.lines


parseEntry :: ConduitM B8.ByteString SimpleLogEntry (ResourceT IO) ()
parseEntry = CA.conduitParserEither parseLogLine =$= awaitForever go
    where
        go (Left err) = liftIO $ putStrLn ("Got an error: " ++ CA.errorMessage err)
        go (Right (_, logEntry)) = yield logEntry


sink :: Sink SimpleLogEntry (ResourceT IO) ()
sink = CL.mapM_ (\t -> liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Got a status: " ++ (show . status) t)


main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ logLines $= parseEntry $$ sink
```

When running `main` I get this output:

```
Got a status: 200
Got a status: 404
Got a status: 500
Got an error: Failed reading: takeWhile1
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the pipeline terminates at this point, rather that continuing to parse the next line of the file, as I'd like to do. Reading the docs for `Data.Conduit.Attoparsec`, this seems like exactly the use case `conduitParserEither` was designed for.

### UPDATE

Per @Fabian, it turns out that `conduitParserEither` wasn't really what I wanted here. Here's a definition of `parseEntry` that does what I wanted to do:

```
parseEntry' :: ConduitM B8.ByteString SimpleLogEntry (ResourceT IO) ()
parseEntry' = (CL.map (parseOnly parseLogLine)) =$= awaitForever go
    where
        go (Left err) = liftIO $ putStrLn ("Got an error: " ++ err)
        go (Right logEntry) = yield logEntry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `conduitParser` (or `conduitParserEither`) can also consume multiple tokens on one line: for example the following input produces the same result:

```
200 GET404 POST
500 GET
FOO
301 PUT
302 GET
201 POST
```

So it makes sense that the parser doesn't continue because it doesn't know where the next token would begin.